# How to extract only the 6-digit number from this Powershell regular-expression script?

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell script :

```
$sentMail.Items | % { $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject ,"Request\s\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value} }
```

and this gives me an output like so :

```
Request 123456
Request 223456
Request 443456
Request 923456
....
```

But I want to only get the 6-digit numbers (from the subjet-lines that have "Request" in them ).

This is what I tried , I tried to pipe the result again:

```
$sentMail.Items | % { $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject ,"Request\s\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value} } | % {$RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject, "\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value}}
```

but I get this error:

```
ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the "{ $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject, "\d{6}")
; if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value} }" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock
".
At line:1 char:120
+ $sentMail.Items | % { $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject, "Request\s\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value}} |
 % <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that the `$Result` items piped at the end of the line would have lost the TaskSubject Property header.  Given that I think this would work better.

```
$sentMail.Items | %{ $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject ,"Request\s\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value} } |%{$Result=[regex]::Match($_,"\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value}}
```

Or you could just skip the second Regex and use the split method.

```
%{$_.split(" ")[1]}
```

Comment: No problem.  The better way to do this I think would be to incorporate the split method into the first for each loop like...  `$sentMail.Items | %{$Result=[regex]::Match($_,"\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value.split(" ")[1]}}` This seems more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your second example is based on the code block and parenthesis placement. Try and make the code readable and place it on multiple lines and you will see what I mean.

As for the the first code where you are close to what you want: If you don't want to return the "request" in the result you should just be able to use a non capture group

```
$sentMail.Items | % { $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject ,"(?:Request\s)\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value} }
```

**Update**

Apparently non capture dont work as expected so we use a look behind instead as it accomplishes the same goal. Updated the logic to process the results as well.

```
$sentMail.Items | %{[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject,'(?<=Request\s)\d{6}')} | ?{$_.Success} | %{$_.value}
```

**Output**

```
123456
223456
443456
923456
```

Comment: Hi Matt, not sure why -but this will return exactly what I used to get - "Request XYZXYZZ"

Comment: Sorry bout that. Will test and see if i'm crazy

Comment: @Coffee. If you are still interested how about the code under update?

Answer (score 1):

I'll toss an answer in here too, since I answered this in a response comment for another of your questions. What I would do is pipe the emails into a Where statement that matches the 6 digits in a subject line (unless you are actually working with Outlook Task objects this should work the same as the TaskSubject), and then pipe that into a ForEach loop that spits out the automatically generated `$Matches` variable. Like this:

```
$sentMail.Items | Where { $_.Subject -match "(\d{6})" } | ForEach { $Matches[1] }
```

I also specify in my RegEx match by enclosing the specified data with parenthesis that it should capture the 6 digits. This isn't super useful for your example, but if, for example, you needed the subject to specifically contain:

Request ######

And you want to only capture the 6 digits you would do -match "Request (\d{6})". This could be used to help if you have, say, emails with subjects that are 'Completed ######' in the folder as well that you do not want to capture.